# NSI service on Win2008R2 using huge amount of RAM over time

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, svchost

I have Remote Desktop Servers running Windows 2008R2. Some with all the latest Windows Updates, some without. All of them, over time, have a svchost process eat up a large amount of RAM (goes up and up... some after a few weeks are above 1GB).

I traced the svchost process to be the NSI - Network Store Interface Service process.

I found these two things on-line about this but none provide a solution.

- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/78e2e4a5-6b03-46a0-917c-e9d76eea7756/svchost-for-nsi-network-store-interface-high-memory-usage
- http://www.networksteve.com/forum/topic.php/Network_Store_Interface_Service_memory_leak/?TopicId=32216&Posts=9

One of those post suggested to unplug and replug the network cable - I tried and the result has been svchost process memory usage suddenly climbing (instead of going down as suggested).

Anyone has experienced and solved that?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running into this: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/nsi-memory-leaks-fixed-yet/f3c3e9db-36a7-45df-9dbd-de9455378498

a memory leak in Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008 R2, introduced when you installed IE10 / IE11.

Workaround until they really fix it: uninstall IE10 and IE11 (and double check afterwards you really have IE9 or IE8). As of now (patched up to 10 July 2014) the issue isn't fixed.